# Android media player seek bar not working

Tags: android, android-studio, media-player, android-seekbar

I am using seek bar media player in dialog, but seek bar does not work when I click on it

I am making call recorder application and using seek to play audio file. When I click on seek bar, it goes forward, but after 1 second it is set back to previous location.

```
   @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_calls_list_row, null);
    holder.playpauseView = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_view);
    holder.playpausebtn = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_btn);
    holder.callfileName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.audiofileName);
    holder.totaltime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.durationtiming);
    holder.callstatus1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.callstatusid);
    holder.btnshare = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    holder.number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number);

    holder.filetimecreated = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.myaudiofiletime);
    holder.filedatecreated = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.myaudiofiledate);

                   if (audioFileList.size() > 0) {
        try {


             mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                   mmr.setDataSource(audioFileList.get(position).getMyfilepath());
            String durationStr = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            int millSecond = Integer.parseInt(durationStr);
            //setting listview totaltime

            holder.totaltime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours((long) millSecond),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) millSecond),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) millSecond) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                    toMinutes((long) millSecond))));

            String filename = audioFileList.get(position).filename;
            final String call_type = filename.substring(25, 33);
            int numlastpositionstr = filename.lastIndexOf("_");
            String call_number = filename.substring(34, numlastpositionstr);
            String call_time = filename.substring(16, 21);
            String call_date = filename.substring(5, 15);
            char[] call_timeArray = call_time.toCharArray();
            for (int x = 0; x < call_timeArray.length; x++) {
                if (call_timeArray[x] == '.') {
                    call_timeArray[x] = ':';
                }
            }
            call_time = String.valueOf(call_timeArray);
            holder.filetimecreated.setText(call_time);
            holder.filedatecreated.setText(call_date);
            String name = getContactDisplayNameByNumber(call_number, context);
            holder.number.setText(call_number);
            holder.callfileName.setText(name);

                    //status incomming or outgoing.

     if (filename.contains(CallStatus.INCOMING) || filename.contains            (CallStatus.incoming)) {
        //            if (call_type.equals(CallStatus.INCOMING) ||          call_type.equals(CallStatus.incoming)) {
                holder.callstatus1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_call_received_black_24dp);
            } else {
                holder.callstatus1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_call_made_black_24dp);
            }
           //            if (call_type.equals(CallStatus.OUTGOING) || call_type.equals(CallStatus.outgoing)) {
                    //                holder.callstatus1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_outgoing);
         //            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exaption is here " + e);
        }
    } else {
              Log.d("audiofilesize", "Audio file size is 0");
    }

    holder.playpausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder audioPlayDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.dialoguelayout, null);
            audioPlayDialog.setView(layout1)
                    .setNeutralButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                            myHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
                            filecompleted = false;
                            running = false;
                        }
                    });
            audioPlayDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        myHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
                        filecompleted = false;
                        running = false;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
            audioPlayDialog.setCancelable(true);
            final ImageButton audioPlayDialogButton = (ImageButton) layout1.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_button);
            audioPlayDialogSeekBar = (SeekBar) layout1.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_seekbar);
            dfilename = (TextView) layout1.findViewById(R.id.dcallnameid);
            remaingtime = (TextView) layout1.findViewById(R.id.dremaingtime);
            totaltime = (TextView) layout1.findViewById(R.id.dtotaltime);
            callstatus = (TextView) layout1.findViewById(R.id.dcallstatus);
            audioPlayDialog.create();
            audioPlayDialog.show();

            String[] call_type1 = getcallstatus(position);
            callstatus.setText(call_type1[0]);
            if (call_type1[1].equals("")) {
                dfilename.setText(call_type1[2]);
            } else {
                dfilename.setText(call_type1[1]);
            }
            audioPlayDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (filecompleted == true) {
                        updateTime();
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                audioPlayDialogButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_48dp);
                            }
                        } else {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                audioPlayDialogButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_48dp);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                        try {
                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    audioPlayDialogButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_48dp);
                                }
                            } else {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    audioPlayDialogButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_48dp);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }


            });

            audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    Log.d("Progress changed", "progress changed" + progress);
                    audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    Log.d("starttracking", "progress starTT");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });

            final Uri data = Uri.parse(audioFileList.get(position).getMyfilepath());

            System.out.println("file Path is here" + data.getPath());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {


                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        finalTime = mp.getDuration();
                        running = true;
                        mp.start();
                        //      audioPlayDialogSeekBar = true;
                        audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                        if (finalTime != 0) {
                            totaltime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours((long) finalTime),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                                    toMinutes((long) finalTime))));
                        }
                    }

                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            myHandler = new Handler();
            totaltime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours((long) finalTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                    toMinutes((long) finalTime))));

            updateTime();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                audioPlayDialogButton.setBackgroundResource    (R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_48dp);
            }
            firsttime = false;

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                    audioPlayDialogButton.setBackgroundResource    (R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_48dp);
                    filecompleted = true;
                    startTime = 0;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    checkpoint = true;
                    mp.seekTo(10);
                    mp.pause();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        private void updateTime() {
            UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (running == true) {
                        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    }
                    if (filecompleted == true) {
                        if (checkpoint) {
                            startTime = 0;
                            checkpoint = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (startTime > (finalTime - 100)) {
                        remaingtime.setText("00:00:00");

                    } else {
                        remaingtime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours((long) startTime),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                                toMinutes((long) startTime))));
                        audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);
                        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    }

                }
            };

            myHandler1 = new Handler();
            UpdateSongTime1 = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            };
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime, 100);

        }
    });
    holder.btnshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //  final Uri data = Uri.parse(audioFileList.get(position).getMyfilepath());
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File   (audioFileList.get(position).getMyfilepath())));
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    return rowView;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you call the media.seekTo(position)?  As far as I can see, you have not called that on your seekbarchangelistener.

And as you are always setting the seekbar position relative to your song progress.. it will always go back to the previous state..

Solution:
In your seekbarchangelistener.. use the onSeekbarchanged and use (Media player).seekTo(position)

Comment: yes but explain me where i use seekbarchangelistener nad how to use i didnot understand brother

Comment: audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                        Log.d("Progress changed", "progress changed" + progress);
                        audioPlayDialogSeekBar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                    }

I am using this

Comment: when i use in this lisner voice stuck ...(mediaPlayer).seekTo(progress);

Comment: did you do this: mediaPlayer.seekTo(position) within your onProgressChanged listener?

Comment: Yes i use this  mediaPlayer.seekTo(position) it working but sound play like stuck or slow motion

Comment: Please help me @androCoder-BD
Today is my last day of this project

Comment: do you have your project on git? if so then please provide your project link.

Comment: Brother i have no this project on git
Sure brother i am waiting your reply
Advance thanks

Comment: if you find out any solution then please help me Thanks

Comment: Hi brother.. sorry for the delay.. mp.seekTo(targetPosition) is working completely fine with me.. If you are still struggling with this.. please upload your code to any git server and share the git url pls.

Answer (score 1):

```
  try {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || mediaPlayer != null) {
                            if (fromUser)
                                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                        } else if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Media is not running",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            seekBar.setProgress(0);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("seek bar", "" + e);
                        seekBar.setEnabled(false);

                    }
```

**I use this code and issue resolved**